# How can I avoid \n while converting CSV to JSON (Pandas)

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am converting a csv file. A short contents of the csv is this:

```
<div class="post-body entry-content" id="post-body-5981440554017350027">
<center><script async="" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

As you can see a new line is introduced after `id="post-body-5981440554017350027">`

Code i am using to convert CSV to JSON is:

```py
import pandas as pd

csv_file = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=",", header=0,
                index_col=False, encoding='utf-8-sig'))
csv_file.to_json("newJsonfile.json", orient="records", date_format="epoch",
                 double_precision=10, force_ascii=True, date_unit="ms",
                 default_handler=None)
```

After conversion to JSON a new `\n` is introduced to every line. This is what I meant:

```
<div class=\"indirectlink\" id=\"post-body-5981440554017350027\">\n<center><script async=\"\" src=\"https://pagead2
```

Is it possible to avoid `\n` characters and convert as it is present in the CSV?

Comment: That's not CSV at all. It looks like you are reading HTML. CSV stands for comma-separated values; clearly you do not have any comma-separated values in this input.

Comment: What do you hope for the resulting JSON to contain anyway?  There are no fields here so no obvious structure we could produce from this input.

Comment: if i pasted the CSV, then you will probably consider it a Spam.So, only a part is good, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, we might wnat to try to change the json a little bit as a string, and then save it. Therefore, we can do the following:

```
json_file = csv_file.to_json(orient = "records", date_format = "epoch",   double_precision = 10, force_ascii = True, date_unit = "ms", default_handler = None)
json_file = json_file.replace(r"\n","")
```

And now we can save it as a json:

```
file = open("newJsonfile.json", "w") 
file.write(json_file) 
file.close()
```

Comment: its still the same. \n\n\n is still in the json output . here : \n\n<script>\n     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});\n<

Comment: Perhaps you should try it in the column specifically

Comment: The csv doesnt have any \n Sir. This is added after i convert the csv to json

Comment: Then we should remove it after creating the json file.

Comment: This is the csv, i copied it for you : <div class="post-body entry-content" id="post-body-4661512838919547187">
<center><script async="" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>